# Docker compose up keep replace existing container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I got the code from two branches with following config:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    build: .
    restart: always
    image: XXXXX
    entrypoint: ["./run.sh"]
    container_name: XXXX
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app

    depends_on:
      - redis
  redis:
    container_name: XXXXX
    image: redis:4-alpine
```

When I docker compose first branch, it works well, but when I compose up the second branch, the original container become the new branch container, which I want the two branches containers exist at the same time.

When I compose up the second branch code, the following message shows:

```
Recreating XXXXX_branch2 ... done
Attaching to XXXXX_branch1
```

Comment: Can't you give different service/container names? Also it won't be possible to run both containers on port 8000 of localhost at the same time.

Comment: The containers name are like project_branch1, project_branch2 and I've specify 8000 and 8001 for these two containers.

Comment: Can not test now, but does this help: docker-compose -p "branch-1" up -d --build and  docker-compose -p "branch-2" up -d --build

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Docker compose associates the container with the project name (default directory name) and the service name or container_name if specified. Thus in case both branches have the compose file under the same directory name, and thus the compose files will be interpreted as refering to the same container, which will lead to the container being recreated.

To avoid this situation, you can the `--project-name` option to override the default one (directory name).

```
docker-compose --project-name branch1 up -d
docker-compose --project-name branch2 up -d
```

In this case both containers will be created.

But note that if both compose files have the same `container_name` set, there will be a conflict and the second container creation will fail. To avoid that, either use different container names, or remove the `container_name` property,  to get the default container name which is `<project_name>_<service_name>_1`

Comment: I want to hug you! Haha.. this fixed my deployment issue. Big thank you 