# How to create two docker compose containers on one server

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                          COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                              NAMES
8a58a0898843   repo.com/test_nginx_dev    "..."   3 seconds ago   Up 2 seconds   80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp     test_nginx_dev
a1fzd92a1c9d   repo.com/test_django_dev   "..."   3 seconds ago   Up 2 seconds   8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8100->8100/tcp   test_django_dev
```

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                     COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                NAMES
7516491ae772   repo.com/test2_nginx_dev    "..."   7 seconds ago   Up 5 seconds   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   test2_nginx_dev
59a344089c51   repo.com/test2_django_dev   "..."   7 seconds ago   Up 6 seconds   8080/tcp             test2_django_dev
```

First, test2_nginx_dev and test2_django_dev were created with docker-compose. After that, if I create test_nginx_dev and test_django_dev with docker-compose
test2_nginx_dev and test2_django_dev disappear. how do i solve it

Comment: please show us your `docker-compose.yaml` configs

Comment: yes show your docker-compose file

Comment: How are you launching the second set of containers; what are the actual commands you're running?  [Docker compose up keep replace existing container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48557607/docker-compose-up-keep-replace-existing-container) has some discussion of a similar setup that may help you.