# Docker compose takes wrong container down

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two APIs. One is located in `/first_project/api` and the other in `/another_project/api`.

Both have `docker-compose.yml` inside them. And this is their respective `docker-compose.yml` files:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    api:
        image: custom_image_name
        container_name: first_project_api
        working_dir: /first_project/api
        ports:
            - 52148:5000
        volumes:
            - /first_project/api:/first_project/api
        command: >
            bash -c
            "
            dotnet Api.dll
            && tail -f /dev/null
            "
        networks:
            - first_project_network

networks:
    first_project_network:
        name: first_project_network
        driver: bridge
```

The second one, is like this one. Just `first_project` is replaced with `second_project`.

However, when I use `docker-compose down` in any of the API directories, docker brings down the other container as well.

What's happening here? How can I debug this?

Comment: This seems like basically the same case as [Docker compose up keep replace existing container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48557607/docker-compose-up-keep-replace-existing-container): since both directories are named `api`, Compose thinks they're the same project and you don't want the "old" containers any more.  Does setting the Compose project name as described in that question help?

Comment: @DavidMaze that's not the problem. Because on another server, tens of containers are all running, with the `api` as their service name. That's basically an internal `hostname` that is used over the docker network. And since we use different networks, then they don't clash.

Comment: You can not use one host port 52148 with both containers

Comment: The name `api` in the file shouldn't matter; the fact that both host directories are named `api` would lead to the conflict.